# Check if an async call has completed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, .net-3.5

I have two class `View` and `Presenter`.

```
class Presenter 
{ 
    View _view;

    void OnViewLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _view.UpdateUIAsync();
        // need to
        // _view.UpdateUIAsync().then(....)
    }
```

Now I want the method `OnViewLoad` to execute some code after `_view.UpdateUIAsync()` is done. Right now my solution is modifying `View.UpdateUIAsync()` to accept an action parameter `_view.UpdateUIAsync(Action<object> after)` and let `View` to execute it after the async code complete. Is it a nicer way to do it like promise pattern?

The class `View`, which is a Winform form, use `BackgroundWorker` to do async since it uses .Net 3.5.

Comment: `Task` is probably the closest thing to promises which is part of .Net Framework (there is version for 3.5 too - [RxExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610.aspx#dotnet)).

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to a later version of .Net you can return a task from UpdateUIAsync

**.Net 4.5.**

```
await _view.UpdateUIAsync() // .Net 4.5
// statement after
```

**.Net 4**

```
_view.UpdateUIAsync().ContinueWith(...) // .Net 4.0
```

If you cant upgrade I guess you have to stick with a callback (like you have) or add an event which fires when the operation has completed.